# add spinner in the place of button on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a spinner below or in the place of the button on click event. I am trying with something like this.

not able to get this working.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxv3oLup/).

```
<div class = "example test">
  <img src="http://www.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211776983.png" onclick="$('.test').click();">  
  <div id="justamoment" style="text-align: left;font-family:  Signika;color: white;font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: none;visibility:hidden">
  <p>
     <img src="http://www.ajaxload.info/cache/FF/FF/FF/00/00/00/1-0.gif" height="12" width="12" Just a moment..
   </p>
   </div>
      <script>
       $(".test").change(function(){
     $("#justamoment").css("visibility","visible");
 });
      </script>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a click handler not change

```
$(".test").click(function () {
    $("#justamoment").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ly22vwnb/)

Comment: oops, whatta shame! Thanks

Comment: What If I want to hide the button and replace the place of button with the spinner?

Answer (score 1):

What about this :

```
 $(".test").click(function () {
    $("#justamoment").css("visibility", "visible");
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/gxv3oLup/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

USe '`click`' instead of '`change`' . It will work

[Wokring fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxv3oLup/2/) fine